# Difference between equivalences classes and congruence classes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, congruences, equivalence-relations

I am really upset as I am not able to understand the difference between **Equivalence Class** $[x]=\{y \in G \mid yEx\}$  and the terms like $[0], [1], [2]$ etc. for $\mathbb{Z}_3$.

Please help me to understand the real meaning of these two.

Answer (score 2):

Each element $[a]$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is an equivalence class.  To be precise, $[a]$ is the set of all integers $x$ which are congruent to $a \mod n$.  So,
$$
[a] = \{x \in \mathbb{Z} \mid x \equiv a \mod n\}.
$$
The right-hand side is the literal definition of the equivalence class of $a$ when the relation is specified to congruence mod $n$.

Comment: Thank You Randall, accept my regards.

Comment: When we write.  Z2 = {  [0] , [1 ] }, then what do the terms [0 ] and [ 1 ] mean ?